# Kronecker products and basis contractions (ie. B.A.Transpose[B]) in C?

Tags: linear-algebra, c, lapack, blas

I  have implemented a basis transformation in C of the following form

```
kron[A,A]*B*Transpose[kron[A,A]]
```

where `A` and `B` are matrices and `kron` is the Kronecker product.

However, my naive code is not scalable, and I am looking for a library to achieve this. My starting point was to look in BLAS and LAPACK for Kronecker products and basis contractions (ie. `B*A*Transpose[B]`) but from my reading of the documentation these are not in the standard build, is there an efficient way to achieve this using these packages (in particular the contraction)?

Comment: How large are your matrices?

Comment: If $A$ is suitably large, it may make sense to just perform the multiplication block-wise directly with gemm.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, you are correct that there is no two-sided matrix multiplication routine $BAB^T$ in BLAS/LAPACK (but I could easily have missed it).

For the symmetric case, I have found code for this operation in [Slicot](http://slicot.org/objects/software/shared/doc/MB01RD.html) and [Elemental](http://libelemental.org/documentation/dev/blas_like/level3/TwoSidedTrmm.html). The latter is a library for parallel linear algebra, so it is a different setting. If you can get your hands on a copy of MB01RD from Slicot, it should be best suited to your needs. The library is available free of charge for academic users.

If the matrix $C$ in $BCB^T$ is symmetric, then another possibility is changing your algorithm to work with symmetric factors of $C$, for instance $C=LDL^T$ with $D$ diagonal. Now to perform your two-sided conjugation you only have to replace $L$ with $BL$.